# CSS border animation working in Chrome, Firefox, but not Edge 15/IE 11

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-animations

A simple css animation changing the colour of the border of a div works on Firefox and Chrome, but not Edge 15 nor presumably IE 11.

I'm testing on Edge 15 via browserstack. I've tried playing with prefixes but without any luck.

```css
div {
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0% { left: 0px; border: 9px solid green; }
  100% { left: 200px; border: 10px solid blue; }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wf95qxsm/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in IE11 if you define the starting property in the original definition

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  border: 9px solid green;
  /* this */
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    border: 9px solid green;
  }
  100% {
    left: 200px;
    border: 10px solid blue;
  }
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    border: 9px solid green;
  }
  100% {
    left: 200px;
    border: 10px solid blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```